# getting a method as a json data in angularjs and how to use it

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have been working on an ui chart that takes data from my json and show it..
my json file is job.json

```js
  {
        "days": [{
          "dayname": "Sun,23 Aug 2015",
          "date": "2015-08-23",
          "hours": "hoursArray()"
        }, {
          "dayname": "Mon,24 Aug 2015",
          "date": "2015-08-24",
          "hours": "hoursArray()"
        }, {
          "dayname": "Tue,25 Aug 2015",
          "date": "2015-08-25",
          "hours": "hoursArray()"
        }, {
          "dayname": "Wed,26 Aug 2015",
          "date": "2015-08-26",
          "hours": "hoursArray()"
        }]
```

in which hoursarray() is a method but while using it in my code as an expression
its not giving any result as when i was giving hardcoded value in angularjs controller. so please if you could tell me how to pass a hoursarray() method in my angularjs

the code for my angularjs file is

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myDashboardApp", []);
var array24 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23];
myApp.controller("mainController", function($scope,$http) {
 
  $http.get("job.json")
  .success(function(response) {
$scope.big = response;
});
 
 $scope.addition = function(index, add) {
  return Number(index) + Number(add);
 };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#scheduleApp").schedule();
});
function hoursArray(from) {
 var output = [];
 for (var i in from) {
  output.push(zeropreffix(i));
 }
 return output;
}

function zeropreffix(i) {
 return (String(i).match(/^[0-9]$/)) ? "0" + i : i;
}

function flightTime( hours) {
 var output = [];
 for (var i in hours) {
  if (i != 0 && i % 2 == 0) {
   output.push({
    breakhours : {
     station : "COK"
    }
   });
  } else {
   output.push({
    timing : {
     real : {
      start : zeropreffix(i) + ":00",
      end : zeropreffix(i) + ":59",
      code : "EK531"
     },
     actual : {
      start : zeropreffix(i) + ":00",
      end : zeropreffix(i) + ":59",
      code : "EK531"
     }
    }
   });
  }

 }
 return output;
}
```

**EDIT** This is the html i am using you can see that i am inserting hours in the *<>* file:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
  Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>Dashboard</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="USER">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css" />
 </head>
 <body  ng-app="myDashboardApp">
  <div class="section-main">
   <div class="schedule" id="scheduleApp"  ng-controller="mainController">
   
    <div class="schedule-row">
     <div class="schedule-route pad0px border-r-dark-blue-fade">
      <div class="schedule-table schedule-field-head bg-dark-blue" data-row="0">
       <span class="schedule-cell"> UTC </span>
       <span class="schedule-cell text-linetight text-center"> <span>+</span> <span>-</span> </span>
       <span class="schedule-cell">00:00</span>
      </div>
      <div class="schedule-table schedule-field-head" ng-repeat="route in big.route" data-row="{{addition($index,1)}}">
       <span class="schedule-cell bg-{{route.stylename}}">{{route.name}}</span>
       <span class="schedule-cell text-center bg-{{route.stylename}}"><span class="circle-icon" ng-hide="!route.info.icon"><i class="fa {{route.info.icon}}"></i></span></span>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="schedule-content valign-top pad0px">
      <div class="schedule-content-inner" id="scheduleContentInner">
       <div class="schedule-drag-wrap">
        <div class="schedule-current-time-marker">
         <span class="schedule-time-marker-pills">00:00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="schedule-h-divider" ng-repeat="dayitem in big.days" data-divider="{{$index}}"></div>
        <div class="schedule-table row-minh bg-dark-blue"  data-row="0" id="scheduleAllDays">
         <div class="schedule-cell pad0px after-left-border" ng-repeat="dayitem in big.days" data-row="{{addition($index,1)}}" data-date="{{dayitem.date}}">
          <div class="schedule-row">
           <div class="schedule-dayname pad-y10px pad-l20px">
            {{dayitem.dayname}}
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="schedule-row border-t-dark-blue-fade">
           *<span class="schedule-cell schedule-hours" ng-repeat="hour in dayitem.hours" data-col-hours="{{hours}}"> {{hour}} </span>*
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="schedule-table row-minh schedule-pills-container" ng-repeat="route in big.route"  data-row="{{addition($index,1)}}" data-flight-row="flight-{{addition($index,1)}}">
         <div class="schedule-cell">
          <div class="schedule-block">
           <div class="schedule-cell pad0px" ng-repeat="flight in route.flight" >
            <div class="schedule-table bg-{{flight.timing.real.color}} radius2px" ng-if="flight.timing.real" data-flight-record="duration~{{flight.timing.real.duration}}|start~{{flight.timing.real.start}}|end~{{flight.timing.real.end}}">
             <span class="schedule-cell pad-r0px" ng-if="flight.timing.real.start">{{flight.timing.real.start}}</span>
             <span class="schedule-cell pad-r0px" ng-if="flight.timing.real.code">{{flight.timing.real.code}}</span>
             <span class="schedule-cell pad-r0px" ng-if="flight.timing.real.end">{{flight.timing.real.end}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="schedule-table text-center" ng-if="flight.breakhours" data-flight-record="duration~{{flight.breakhours.duration}}|start~{{flight.breakhours.start}}|end~{{flight.breakhours.end}}">
             <span class="pad-x2px">{{flight.breakhours.station}}</span>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="schedule-table autowidth">
           <div class="schedule-cell pad0px" ng-repeat="flight in route.flight" >
            <div class="schedule-table bg-{{flight.timing.actual.color}} radius2px" ng-if="flight.timing.actual" data-flight-record="duration~{{flight.timing.actual.duration}}|start~{{flight.timing.actual.start}}|end~{{flight.timing.actual.end}}">
             <span class="schedule-cell pad-r0px" ng-if="flight.timing.actual.start">{{flight.timing.actual.start}}</span>
             <span class="schedule-cell pad-r0px" ng-if="flight.timing.actual.code">{{flight.timing.actual.code}}</span>
             <span class="schedule-cell pad-r0px" ng-if="flight.timing.actual.end">{{flight.timing.actual.end}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="schedule-table" ng-if="flight.breakhours.maintenance" data-flight-record="duration~{{flight.breakhours.maintenance.duration}}|start~{{flight.breakhours.maintenance.start}}|end~{{flight.breakhours.maintenance.end}}">
             <span class="schedule-cell pad-y0px" ng-if="!flight.breakhours.maintenance.blank"> <span class="schedule-table bg-{{flight.breakhours.maintenance.color}} radius2px" > <span class="schedule-cell">{{flight.breakhours.maintenance.reason}}</span> <span class="schedule-cell text-right"><i class="fa {{flight.breakhours.maintenance.icon}}" ng-if="flight.breakhours.maintenance.icon"></i> {{flight.breakhours.maintenance.time}}</span> </span> </span>
             <div class="schedule-cell pad0px" ng-if="flight.breakhours.maintenance.blank">
              {{flight.breakhours.maintenance.blank}}
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
         <div class="schedule-cell">
          &nbsp;
         </div>
         <!-- <div class="schedule-cell" ng-if="flight==null">&nbsp;</div> -->
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="schedule-route pad0px border-l-dark-blue-fade valign-top overflow-visible">
      <div class="schedule-table schedule-field-head bg-dark-blue" data-row="0">
       <span class="schedule-cell"> UTC </span>
       <span class="schedule-cell text-linetight text-center"> <span>+</span> <span>-</span> </span>
       <span class="schedule-cell">00:00</span>
      </div>
      <div class="schedule-table schedule-field-head" ng-repeat="route in big.route" data-row="{{addition($index,1)}}">
       <span class="schedule-cell bg-{{route.stylename}}">{{route.name}}</span>
       <span class="schedule-cell text-center bg-{{route.stylename}}"><span class="circle-icon" ng-hide="!route.info.icon"><i class="fa {{route.info.icon}}"></i></span></span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="schedule.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "hoursArray()" in your code will be treated as a string. You can use something like eval() function to run expression in this string. But it's depends on your scenario (how your are going to use received data).

Comment: can you please tell me how to use eval

Answer (score 0):

JSON format strings are like a XML strings: just a way to send data. You cannot send executable code in a JSON (well, there is a way using `eval`, but it is not a good idea).

If I am receiving a JSON structure from a server, I'd expect that all the data I need is already present, so the `hours` array should be populated in server side. If I had to populate a field once I receive the response, then I'll choose how to do so instead receiving the code from server side. You can accept a "hint" about how to populate it or not, but no the code itself.

So, to summarize:

1. Ensure the data is populated in server side, or
2. Populate it in client side with your own method.

For example:

```
 function hoursArray() {...};
  var data;
  $http.get('job.json').success(function(response) {
    data=JSON.parse(response);
    for (var i=0;i<data.days.length;i++) {
      data.days.hours=hoursArray();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The is at least one way to do that without using `eval`. First, pass only the function name without parentheses, i.e. a `day` object will look like that:

```
// day object:
{
    "dayname": "Sun,23 Aug 2015",
    "date": "2015-08-23",
    "hours": "hoursArray"
}
```

Then in the controller, declare the function as a property of the controller:

```
myApp.controller("mainController", function ($scope, $http) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.hoursArray = function () {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you can dynamically get the function like that:

```
vm[day.hours]
```

Comment: i tried your method its not showing any result i am working on a testing file in plunker please have a look at it
[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/luy38x3XnpCiYF6WXaCZ?p=preview)